# Run JS function after delay after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am running a very simple function atm that runs on page load. However whilst the page has finished loading, it sometimes takes half a second or so for the content itself to actually pop up. This wouldn't normally be an issue but one of my variables relies on content that is loaded is it possible to run the JS function 2 seconds AFTER the page has been loaded? I know I could just use a timeout but surely if the user is on slow internet and it takes longer than that for the page to load, it will run before it is ready?

The code I have written and am using is here:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {


    var subTotal = $("span.wsite-price").html();
        alert (subTotal);

  });
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: on `DOMContentLoaded/ready`, `setTimeout` of 2 seconds, then call function, please decode this and you'll get answer

Comment: If you put the setTimeout call within the window load call it won't execute until the page has loaded.

Comment: How does the HTML of `<span class="wsite-price"></span>` get populated? Perhaps there is an "on completion"-like event that can be used, especially if you are using AJAX or a jQuery framework. This way, you won't _have_ to wait two seconds _at all_. Just get the info as soon as it's available, whether it takes 10 seconds or 80 milliseconds

Comment: I agree with Jacob, you need to show how the value is getting populated, then likely use a callback.

Comment: @JacobStamm I am simply using it as follows `<span class="wsite-price">200</span>`

Comment: @dwinnbrown if that's the case, then your current code works just fine. As some others stated, the `window.load` event doesn't happen _on_ load, it happens upon _completion_ of the page loading. Same thing as jQuery's `$(document).ready(function () { //code here });`

Answer (score 0):

Because your `<span class="wsite-price">200</span>` is not loaded dynamically, but is part of the static HTML document, your current code will work fine. Nothing inside `$(window).bind("load", function() { //code here })` gets executed until the page is finished loading.

Comment: Try using jQuery's `$(document).ready(function() { //code here })` instead, see if you get the desired behavior